# Layout with display:inline-block not line oriented

Tags: html, css

I'm having some problems with the layout of this page:
http://ulrichbangert.de/div/webdesign/php/bottle-library/hellyers.php
If the viewport width is set to a medium value (about 800px) the layout is not line oriented. In some lines there only few bottles although there would be space for more. Is there a way to fix this, maybe by using bootstrap? It would be best if the bottoms of the containers would be aligned.
My CSS:

```
        .photo-link {
            max-width: 300px;
            display: inline-block;
            float: left;
            text-align: center;
            font-size:medium;
            padding:5px;
            margin:5px;
            border:3px solid #663366;         
        }
```

My HTML:

```
<a href="i/360widex43high.jpg" class="photo-link fancybox" title="360widex43high">
<img src="t/360widex43high.jpg" /><br>360widex43high</a>
<a href="i/43widex360high.jpg" class="photo-link fancybox" title="43widex360high">
<img src="t/43widex360high.jpg" /><br>43widex360high</a>
```

Comment: Problem already solved: I forgot to remove the "float:left" in the CSS. Now the layout is line oriented as I expected and the images are bottom-aligned.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want every image to have different image size? Id say its more easier to fill every blank space if you have the same height on every image.